# Removing Tab Indicator from ViewPager

Tags: android

I have a `ViewPager` that contains multiple tabs. There is a tab indicator at the top of the screen (the black strip in the following picture). How do I disable the tab indicator?

Here's the code if needed:

```
    // ViewPager
ViewPager pager;
TeamTabAdapter tabAdapter;

REvent event;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(R.style.Backup);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_team_viewer);

    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.actionbar)));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    event = (REvent) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("event");
    RTeam team = (RTeam) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("team");
    RForm form = new Loader(getApplicationContext()).loadForm(event.getID());

    tabAdapter = new TeamTabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), event, team, form);
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    pager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);

    pager.setAdapter(tabAdapter);
    pager.setCurrentItem(1);
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Removing Tab Indicator from ViewPager

Remove the `PagerTabStrip` from the layout. It will be a child of the `ViewPager`.

> How do I disable the tab indicator?

You can try calling `setEnabled(false)` on the `PagerTabStrip`, though I do not know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure . But try adding transparent color like below in your TabLayout tag in xml

```
app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

This line `app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"` solve the problem for me in xml.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_bottom_tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"             //this line
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />
```